Could the laws of physics be subjective
I was writing a personal text and this question came to me. Could someone enlighten me.
In my view, a convention that the laws of physics were subjective would be the same as Peter and John having different apples, instead of sharing the same apple.
How could we do an experiment to see if the laws of physics are objective or subjective?


https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05080

I’m not sure the universe is an entity that can be obliged to begin with.

The double-slit experiment has already proven the subjectivity of the universe, due to the fact that the experiment changes according to the observer. It's a local multiverse. But when observers interact with each other, these local multiverses more closely resemble an objective universe.

Local multiverses may have different laws of physics

@felipemuniz you are misunderstanding the double slit experiment. The "observer" is a sensor, it has nothing to do with humans.

Neuron is a sensor and also has nothing to do with humans, or does it?

Physics is based on experimental evidence. Almost always, observers agree on the results of experiments (although they may disagree on the interpretation of these results). If physics is subjective then the whole world outside myself and everything in it  is subjective, which takes us into the realm of solipsism.

This is how we find true freedom, where understanding others and oneself overcomes the imposition of a false truth.

Objective means that different people get the same answer when performing the same experiment. Physicists often refer to this as reproducibility, meaning that others should be able to reproduce the same experiment, using the published specifications/protocols - the discoveries that are not reproduced quickly become problematic. The caveat is that, if successfully reproduced, the later textbooks cite only the first experiment.

This is entirely in the realm of philosophy, which has nothing to do with physics.
